# Анимация при скроле

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Такая задача:
При любом скроле выполняется анимация блока. То есть: раз проскролил - виежает блок, еще раз - убирается.

```
$('.scroll-block').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(){
   var intervalID;

    intervalID = setTimeout(
        function(){
            if($(".ser-bottom-text").hasClass("hide")){
                $(".ser-bottom-text").removeClass("hide");

             } else {
                $(".ser-bottom-text").addClass("hide");

             }
        }, 200);
});
```

Нужно сделать так, что бы реакция была после остановки колесика. То есть, какой длины бы не был скрол - после этого происходила анимация (добавление/убирание класса).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

остановка колесика это отсутствие события scroll некоторое время, определите какое время считается остановкой, в текущей реализации вижу только одну проблему - перед setTimeout надо сделать

```
clearTimeout(intervalID);
```

и `var intervalID` надо вынести выше всего этого кода.

ну и для простоты можно вместо кучи условий сделать toggleClass

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var intervalID, $bottomtext = $(".ser-bottom-text");
    $('.scroll-block').on('scroll', toggleBlock);

    function toggleBlock() {
        clearTimeout(intervalID);
        intervalID = setTimeout(function () {
            $bottomtext.toggleClass('hide');
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

[image: демо]