# Изменение высоты при остановке скролла

Tags: jquery, css

День добрый.

Научился отлавливать скролл блока и изменять css-свойства при начале скроллирования:

```
$('.work-page').scroll(function(e){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $("#top .top-menu ul").animate({
                "padding-top" : "20px"
            }, 300);
});
```

А вот теперь возник вопрос - как возвращать дефолтные значения?
Делаю для того, чтобы при начале пролистывания блока `.work-page` у меня header и footer уменьшались по высоте, раздвигая область экрана для просмотра `.work-page` (там список фотографий, и чем больше поле, тем лучше). 
Задача: чтобы при остановке скроллинга header и footer также плавно возвращались к первоначальным своим значениям.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При начале скролла сохраняй начальные значения в дополнительные переменные. По окончании скролла делай animate к значениям этих переменных. Остановку scroll отлавливай через setTimeout.

Вот, например, [Анимация при скроле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/316543/jquery-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5)